# Nav bar and header not scaling properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Here is the site in question [http://www.qsconference.com/](http://www.qsconference.com).

This is a screen shot of the site on a chrome window scaled to mobile size.

[image: web image]

This is a screen shot of the site from an iPhone 7.

[image: web image]

I need help fixing the scaling and navbar collapse on mobile devices.  It seems to work when testing from chrome, but on mobile devices it doesn't work.

This is the code for the collapsable navigation bar:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div id = "nav_bar" class = "navbar-custom">
<nav class = "row navbar navbar-default">
<div class = "container-fluid">

<div class = "navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class = "navbar-brand XX" style = "font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;" href = "#jumbo"><i>QSC</i></a>
  </div>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id = "linkList">
  <li ><a href="#about" class = "XX">QSC 2018</a></li>
  <li><a href="#delegates" class ="XX">Delegates</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sponsorship" class = "XX">Sponsorship</a></li>
  <li><a href="#speakers" class = "XX">Speakers</a></li>
  <li><a href="#team" class = "XX">The Team</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your code, this might help in solving problem

Comment: @komal I added the navigation bar code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add it in head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A  **viewport** element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

`width=device-width` is used to set the width of the document equal to the width of the actual device.

`initial-scale=1.0` is used to set the zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Comment: kindly up vote the answer, so that it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this worked?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: For responsive design it is mandatory to define the viewport definition.

Comment: Explained! hope that would help you.